# Calculate the integral $\int \limits _0 ^1 x^2 \sqrt{4-x^2} \ \Bbb d x$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \limits _0 ^1 x^2 \sqrt{4-x^2}  \ \Bbb dx$$

I tried integration by parts and substitution but I couldn't find the answer.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Chinny84 Sadly, OP never got the chance to answer, since now we have four(!) answers using the same substitution. Incredible, and one reason I don't think this wonderful site is as good as it could be.

Comment: @mickep I thought I had removed my comment (due to the reasons you stated in your comment). I can not judge myself, as I have done this myself. I do think that we should give the OP time to modify the question.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use change variable $u=2cost$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* By the change of variables theorem we have
$$
\int_{x} x^{2}\sqrt{4-x^{2}} = \int_{x = 2\sin \theta} 4\sin^{2}\theta\cdot 2\cos \theta \cdot 2 \cos \theta = 16 \int_{\theta} \sin^{2}\theta \cos^{2} \theta = 16\int_{\theta} (\sin^{2}\theta - \sin^{4}\theta).
$$
Calculating the separate integrals involving $\sin$ may get somewhat lengthy, but try it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: let $x=2\sin\theta \implies dx=2\cos \theta d\theta $ $$\int_{0}^{1} x^2\sqrt{4-x^2}$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\pi/6} 4 \sin^2\theta |2\cos \theta|2\cos \theta d\theta $$
Since,  $0<\theta<\pi/2$ $$=\int_{0}^{\pi/6} 16 \sin^2\theta \cos^2 \theta d\theta $$
$$=16\int_{0}^{\pi/6} \sin^2\theta d\theta-16\int_{0}^{\pi/6} \sin^4\theta d\theta $$
$$=16\int_{0}^{\pi/6} \frac{1- \cos 2\theta}{2} d\theta-16\int_{0}^{\pi/6} \left(\frac{1- \cos 2\theta}{2} \right)^2d\theta $$
Use $\cos^22\theta=\frac{1-\cos4\theta}{2}$  for the second integral

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: Substitute $x=2\sin\theta$ for $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{6}$

Hint 2: Use trigonometric identities (integration by parts for trigonometric expressions is usually lengthy)

$$
\int x^2 \sqrt{4-x^2} \,dx \\
= \int 4 \sin^2 \theta \cdot 2\cos \theta \cdot 2 \cos \theta \,d\theta \\
= 16 \int \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta \,d\theta \\
= 2 \int \sin^22\theta \,d2\theta \\
=\frac12 \int 1-\cos 4\theta \,d4\theta.
$$

When $x=0$, $4\theta = 0$
When $x=1$, $4\theta = 4\pi/6$

$$
\int_0^1 x^2 \sqrt{4-x^2} \,dx \\
=\frac12 \int_0^{4\pi/6} 1-\cos 4\theta \,d4\theta \\
=\frac12([(4\pi/6)-0]-[\sin(4\pi/6)-\sin(0)]) \\
=\frac13\pi-\frac{\sqrt3}{4}.
$$